# How to change AdventureWorks database collation on SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, collation

The challenge is to change the collation for the `AdventureWorks` database from `Latin1_General_CS_AS` to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. Does anyone know how to do it?

I tried this:

```
alter database AdventureWorks set single_user
alter database AdventureWorks collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
alter database AdventureWorks set multi_user
```

But I got following error:

> Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The object 'ufnLeadingZeros' is dependent on database collation. The
>   database collation cannot be changed
>   if a schema-bound object depends on
>   it. Remove the dependencies on the
>   database collation and then retry the
>   operation.
>
> Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The object 'CK_ProductReview_Rating' is dependent
>   on database collation. The database
>   collation cannot be changed if a
>   schema-bound object depends on it.
>   Remove the dependencies on the
>   database collation and then retry the
>   operation.
>
> Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The object 'CK_TransactionHistory_TransactionType'
>   is dependent on database collation.
>   The database collation cannot be
>   changed if a schema-bound object
>   depends on it. Remove the dependencies
>   on the database collation and then
>   retry the operation.
>
> Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The object 'CK_ProductVendor_AverageLeadTime' is
>   dependent on database collation. The
>   database collation cannot be changed
>   if a schema-bound object depends on
>   it. Remove the dependencies on the
>   database collation and then retry the
>   operation.

Then I was trying something like this:

```
DECLARE @NewCollation VARCHAR(255), @DBName sysname

SELECT @NewCollation = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', -- change this to the collation that you need
       @DBName = DB_NAME()

DECLARE @CName varchar(255), 
        @TbleName sysname, 
        @objOwner sysname, 
        @Sql varchar(8000), 
        @Size int, 
        @Status tinyint, 
        @Colorder int

Declare CurWhileLoop cursor read_only forward_only local
for Select
       QUOTENAME(C.Name)
      ,T.Name
      ,QUOTENAME(U.Name) + '.' +QUOTENAME(O.Name)
      ,C.Prec
      ,C.isnullable
      ,C.colorder
    From syscolumns C
      inner join systypes T on C.xtype=T.xtype
      inner join sysobjects O on C.ID=O.ID
      inner join sysusers u on O.uid = u.uid
    where T.Name in ('varchar', 'char', 'text', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'ntext')
      and O.xtype in ('U')
      and C.collation != @NewCollation
    and objectProperty(O.ID, 'ismsshipped')=0
    order by 3, 1

open CurWhileLoop
SET XACT_ABORT ON
begin tran
fetch CurWhileLoop into @CName, @TbleName, @objOwner, @Size, @Status, @Colorder
while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
begin
  set @Sql='ALTER TABLE '+@objOwner+' ALTER COLUMN '+@CName+' '+@TbleName+ isnull ('('
+convert(varchar,@Size)+')', '') +' COLLATE '+ @NewCollation
+' '+case when @Status=1 then 'NULL' else 'NOT NULL' end
  exec(@Sql) -- change this to print if you need only the script, not the action
  fetch CurWhileLoop into @CName, @TbleName, @objOwner, @Size, @Status, @Colorder
end
close CurWhileLoop
deallocate CurWhileLoop
commit tran
```

And I got following error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The multi-part identifier "U.Name" could not be bound.

I was trying to run this last query against `AdventureWorks` database and I got U.Name name error as above, and when I was trying to run this query against master database nothing happens.

Please help!

Comment: The reason for the error in your script against AdventureWorks is that `U` and `u` are not the same in a case sensitive collation. What if you fix those issues and retry? The only way of changing the collation of `master` is to rebuild it.

Comment: When I repair this U issue I got this:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

:(

Comment: `convert(varchar,@Size)` should be `case when @Size = -1 THEN 'Max' else convert(varchar,@Size) end` Note this **still** only changes the collation of the columns not the DB though. You would also need to drop the problem constraints etc, change the **database** collation and add them back.

Comment: can you paste/send me a whole script, please?

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot Martin!! I'm very grateful!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest starting over from scratch. It will take less effort for you compared to your approach above.

Download a [new copy / scripts for SQL Server 2005 AdventureWorks](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/4004).

Ensure your server has the collation you want by default. Right click-Properties->General->Server Collation.

When you create your database with SQL Server Management Studio, you can explicitly choose the collation.

Comment: But on the page that you gave me there are installation components. There are no scripts? Or maybe I can'see them... :(

Comment: The right answer is to use new installation file with CI postfix. (AdventureWorksDBCI.msi)!!